# How to add Focuschange Listner to listview in android

Tags: android, listview, onfocus

I am having a `listview` in one of my activity. How to set focus change listener. I tried with following the block of code I am not getting a result.

```
product_search_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.productlist);
product_search_list.setOnFocusChangeListener(onproductchangelistener);

private OnFocusChangeListener onproductchangelistener = new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        int index= (int) ((ListView)v).getSelectedItemId();
        Log.i("index",""+index);
    }
};
```

Actually, on focus change of list items, I want to get the index of the focused list item and do the necessary operations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `setOnItemSelectedListener()`, not `setOnFocusChangeListener()`.

Comment: Instead of setOnItemSelectedListener(), I am trying to add setOnFocusChangeListener() because the target device is non-touchable device..can you please suggest some links